# add Exists operator in a union sql query

Tags: postgresql, union, exists, sqldatatypes

I have two tables that am using union to combine the result-set of them my problem here is Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns and data types, I don't have the same number of columns so am creating null columns

```
select
d.deal_id as order_id,
EXISTS(select * from table1 c where d.user_id = c.user_id) as IsUser, --this returns boolean value
from table 1 c
union
select
cast(o.id as varchar) as order_id,
coalesce('No_user'::text,'0'::text) as IsUser, --i get an error :UNION types boolean and character varying cannot be matched
from table2 o
```

how can I create a null column in table2 that matches the boolean data type of the table1

Comment: Could you provide the tables content and your desider output?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a null column in table2 that matches the boolean data type of the table1

By putting NULL into the SELECT list of the second query.

Generally (in SQL) the datatype for the column is dictated by the first query in the union set and other queries must match. You don't need column aliases for subsequent queries either, but they may help make a query more readable:

```
select
  d.deal_id as order_id,
  EXISTS(select * from table1 c where d.user_id = c.user_id) as IsUser, --this returns boolean value
from table 1 c
union
select
  cast(o.id as varchar) as order_id,
  null --IsUser
from table2 o
```

If you have a case where the type of the column in the first query is different to what you want in the output, you cast the first column:

```
select 1::boolean as boolcol
UNION
select true
```

This will ensure that the column is boolean, rather than giving a "integer and bool cannot be matched". Remember also that, should you need to, NULL can be cast to a type, e.g. `select null::boolean as bolcol`